# spark streaming - Enrichment + Analytics + storage of events on s3

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, parquet

I have my events coming in from Kinesis, which needs to be enriched.By enrichment I mean, converting ip to location, adding session_id etc. After enrichment I would want to store it on S3 (in parquet) for later analysis, also I would want to get some metrics in realtime ( 3~5 minutes delay is ok ) and store it in redshift.

I thought I can use spark streaming for it, my streaming application can do the enrichment, store in s3 and as well as do the realtime querying.

Following is problem:

- If I set the `BatchDuration` of Spark Stream to 3 minutes, I can get analysis updated at every 3 mins. But it will create one file for every 3 minutes in S3.
- If I set the `BatchDuration` of Spark Stream to 60 minutes, I can get 1 file per hour, but then my analysis is delayed by an hour.
- If I create two different application then I have to repeat the code for enrichment.

Solutions thought of:

- Use 3 minute interval, get lot of files on S3 , run a separate program to combine the files later on, Sounds incorrect- error prone, disaster mismanagement.
- Use two kinesis stream, first application enriches the data and puts it to the second stream. From the Second stream there are two applications at different intervals. Realtime analytics runs at 2-3 minutes and S3 Writer runs at 1 hour interval. - Cost seems to be downside here.

Comment: Would suggest second, as it is less risky implementation. You can go with the first approach if you have a fault-tolerant framework to do the combine jobs.